# How to view kmeans output in matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics, k-means

I have a 2400x12 data which I would like to classify using kmeans. Can anybody tell me how I can see the output of kmeans? Thanks.

Comment: You have a 12 dimensional vector space. You can't view that. It's hard enough to view 3 dimensions. If you want, you can do a PCA analysis and find the best 3 dimensional representation, classify that and view that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other guy said, you can't 'see' 12 dimensions. However, you may be able to use PCA to deal with that (check PCA in wikipedia).
Assuming that the data variable is called Data:

```
[c, s] = princomp(Data);
plot(s(:,1), s(:,2),'.');
```

The rows in s are related to the rows in Data, so you can plot using different symbols for different clusters. For instance:

```
U=kmeans(Data,2);
[c, s] = princomp(Data);
plot (s(U==1,1), s(U==1,2), 'x');
hold on;
plot (s(U==2,1), s(U==2,2), '*');
```